# Cargar nuevos items en un FLateList con React NativeExpo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

Tengo este Flat List y en la consola veo que se cargan nuevos componenetes pero en la pantalla del mobil solo me muestra su espacio

Alguien me puede ayudar  ver lo que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias

La idea es que se cargeuen unos hexagonos uno al lado del otro

Cuando cargo mas hexagonos el flat list no los carga y me queda un espacio vacio

[image: App]
Asi es como se ve la app y no se cargan nuevos hexagonos

//El consturctor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {users,isLoading } = props;

       this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
       this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
      
        this.state = {
        
         data: this.setData(this.props.users)
           };
      }
```

Aqui hago la introduccion de  nuevos datos para el flat list
//Set data
setData = (data)=> {
this.setState({data:data})
}
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
let users=nextProps.users
const columnas=5;
const filas=6;
let n=0;
let dt=[];
console.log("users2: "+users)
while(n<columnas){

```
     let randomUsers =users.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
     randomUsers =randomUsers.slice(0,filas-1)
     console.log("n: "+n + "randomUsers:"+users)
   dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers});
     n++;
     }
     console.log("dt"+dt)
     
 


  this.setState({ data:dt });  
  this.forceUpdate();
}
handleLoadMore2= ()=> {
  /*      
  if(this.state.updating==false){
    this.state.updating=true;
    let dt=this.state.data;
    let users=this.props.users
    if (users!=undefined && dt!= undefined){
    let filas=0
      console.log("dt++"+dt)
      let randomUsers =users.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
      for(let n=0;n<dt.length;n++){
        
        let  user=randomUsers[Math.floor(Math.random()*size(users)-1)%size(users)]
       
       if(user!=undefined)
       dt[n].data.push(user)
        filas=dt[n].data.length;
        console.log("dt****"+dt[n].data)
      }
  
      this.setState({ data:dt,filas:filas});  

   this.state.updating=false;
}
    }*/
};

onEndReached = ({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
  if(!this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum){
      this.handleLoadMore1();
      this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = true;
  }
}
handleLoadMore1() {
  let users=this.props.users
  let dt=[];
  console.log("handleLoad")
  if (users!=undefined && dt!=undefined){
  const filas=this.state.filas;
  let randomUsers =users.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  randomUsers =randomUsers.slice(0,filas-1)
  while(randomUsers.length<filas){
    randomUsers.push(users[Math.floor(Math.random()*size(users)-1)%size(users)])
  }

 let n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;
 console.log("n: "+n + "randomUsers2:"+users)
 dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers,length:randomUsers.length});
 n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;
 console.log("n: "+n + "randomUsers2:"+users)
 dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers,length:randomUsers.length});
 n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;
 console.log("n: "+n + "randomUsers2:"+users)
 dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers,length:randomUsers.length});
 n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;
  console.log("n: "+n + "randomUsers2:"+users)
 dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers,length:randomUsers.length});
this.setState({data:[...this.state.data,...dt ]}); //}
 this.forceUpdate();
  }
};


  renderSecondFlatlist = ({item,index}) => {

      return (
       
        <FlatList  style={item.n% 2==0 ? ({ overflow:'visible',position:'relative',marginLeft:-59,width: 235,height:'100%' }):({overflow:'visible',position:'relative',marginLeft:-59,top:-100, width: 235, height: "100%" })} vertical
          extraData={this.state} 
          data={item.data}
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          vertical
          //onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          //      onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore2()}
        />
       
      );
    
  }

  keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return index.toString();
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {

   // console.log("+++item:"+item.images)
    return (
      <HexagonProfile  user={item} style={{ top: 100, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,width: 235, height: 200 }}/>
    );
  }
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){

return true;



}
  render() {


    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView >
      <FlatList
        extraData={this.state.data}
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderSecondFlatlist
          }
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
              onEndReached={this.onEndReached.bind(this)}
              onMomentumScrollBegin={() => { this.onEndReachedCalledDuringMomentum = false; }}
        horizontal={true}
        horizontal
      />
      </SafeAreaView>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví yo mismo con este código.

```
    handleLoadMore1() {
  let users=this.props.users
  let dt=[];
  console.log("handleLoad")
  if (users!=undefined && dt!=undefined){
  let  scol=2;
 for(let i=0;i<scol;i++){
  let randomUsers =users.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
  randomUsers =randomUsers.slice(0,this.state.filas-1)
  while(randomUsers.length<this.state.filas-1){

    randomUsers.push(users[Math.floor(Math.random()*(size(users)-1))%(size(users))])
    
  }
  console.log("randomUsers:" +randomUsers)
 let n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;

 n= this.state.data.length+dt.length;
 dt.push({n:n ,data:randomUsers,length:randomUsers.length});
}
```